# Can someone please explain this RAID Error message?

Tags: windows, raid, hardware-raid

I have a 8 drive RAID 6 (500x8) on a production server at work.

Yesterday we noticed the server was slow, and after an investigation I found that 2 of the drives in the RAID had failed, and the notification system was not able to send out a email notification. We immediately shut down the server, replaced the 2 drives that had failed, and let them rebuild before rebooting in to windows.

Now the boot back to windows went find, but at times some errors will pop up like this:

```
Puncturing bad block:   PD   Port 0 - 3:0:0      Location   0x209a3686
Puncturing bad block:   PD   Port 4 - 7:0:7      Location   0x209a3686
Unrecoverable medium error during recovery:   PD   Port 0 - 3:0:0      Location   0x209a3686
Puncturing bad block:   PD   Port 0 - 3:0:0      Location   0x209a3686
Puncturing bad block:   PD   Port 4 - 7:0:7      Location   0x209a3686
```

In addition, VMs running on the machine seem to be unable to complete windows updates properly. This may or may not be related.

After investigating a little, I ran a consistency check on the VD, and there are several things that came up, intermixed with more of the same like the above:

```
Consistency Check completed with uncorrectable errors on VD:   0
Consistency Check found inconsistent parity on VD     strip:       ( VD   =   0,   strip       =   1068315)
Consistency Check detected uncorrectable multiple medium     errors:       ( PD   Port 4 - 7:0:7  Location   0x209a3686  VD       0)
Consistency Check found inconsistent parity on VD     strip:       ( VD   =   0,   strip       =   1067493)
Unexpected sense:   PD       =   Port 0 - 3:0:0Unrecovered read error,   CDB   =    0x28 0x00 0x1f 0xac 0x8c 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00    ,   Sense   =    0xf0 0x00 0x03 0x1f 0xac 0x8d 0xdb 0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

I read on one forum where the numbers like 3:0:0 show its drive 0 where the problem is, tho I am not sure since there are multiple ones shown here. (We replaced drives 1 and 5).

Can someone break this down for me? Is there a simple fix, like further replacing and rebuilding other drives?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Usually when there are punctured drives, the RAID data is non trustable any-more. You could try to copy it somewhere else but integrity of data cannot be trusted.

After, kill the whole RAID structure, create a new one with initialisation option to force sanity check of disk.

Best is to actively monitor the RAID state, in order to detect issue at first disk failure and not wait until both have failed.

Time to restore from your backups.

Comment: I am confused, as the raid status says its ok... and everything seems to work properly, aside from a temporary issue where windows update failed on some VMs, but a reboot fixed that.

Comment: Usually punctured block means that corrupted bad block have been copied from failed disks to healthy disks. When a disk failure occurs, RAID manager will try to save the data block to other healthy disk but if the data was already corrupted, it lead to punctured block.

Comment: Only some of the blocks are punctured, that mean some of the data on the disk have been corrupted but the other part is healthy. That explain why you can use some data from the disk. Your issue now is how you can trust the data on the disk as you don't know if it is reliable or not. Are you reading corrupted data, or un-altered data. Mostly your update process is trying to read corrupted data leading to execution failure. But the "OS" part seems not affected so mostly on healthy part. Going like this is dangerous like cleaning after some virus infections.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to DevOps's answer: it is not uncommon for additional errors to surface while rebuilding.

This is commonly attributed to increased stress during rebuild but I've found that not to be true. Stress during heavy workloads doesn't cause read errors. Rather, it's due to previously undetected bit rot on the drives: when data isn't ever read for month or even years some sectors can exceed their error correction, making them unreadable. When these are encountered during rebuild with no redundancy left the rebuild will fail.

So, once you've rebuilt your array, do make sure you turn on **monthly data scrubbing**, media patrol, patrol read, or whatever it's called on your controller. That way any weak sectors will be detected and repaired in time. If your controller doesn't have that option run a monthly image-to-null on the full logical drive (e.g. using *dd*).